# Keep selected state of UITableViewCells when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to keep the selected state of multiple cells on a `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. I have an edit button that I've set up that loops through every cell to select each field on my UITableView.

Here is the code for the edit button on tap that selects all my rows.

```
- (IBAction)editButtonTapped:(id)sender {

for (int i = 0; i < self.caseDataTableView.numberOfSections; i++) {
    for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.caseDataTableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; r++) {
        [self tableView:caseDataTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:i]];
    }
}
```

}

When calling the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, it does the following code.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
OKOperatieNoteTableViewCell *cell = (OKOperatieNoteTableViewCell *)[self.caseDataTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.cellIndexPath = indexPath;
[cell hideLabelAndShowButtons];}
```

Incase you were wondering here is the `hideLabelAndShowButtons` method.

```
- (void)hideLabelAndShowButtons {
self.caseDataKeyLabel.hidden = NO;

if (!self.disabled) {
    self.caseDataValueLabel.hidden = YES;
    self.textField.hidden = NO;
    if ([self.inputType isEqualToString:@"switcher"] || [self.inputType isEqualToString:@"multiselect"] || [self.inputType isEqualToString:@"picker"] || [self.inputType isEqualToString:@"DatePicker"] || [self.inputType isEqualToString:@"selectContact"]) {
        self.button.hidden = NO;
    }else {
        self.button.hidden = YES;
    }
}

self.caseDataDescriptionTextView.hidden = YES;}
```

Now at this point, I have all my rows selected. If I scroll down and then back up the selection of these rows is not there anymore. Now I'm aware when you go in and out of the view, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method recreates these cells. The following is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"caseData";
OKOperatieNoteTableViewCell * cell = [[OKOperatieNoteTableViewCell alloc]init];

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (indexPath.row < _procedureVariables.count) {
    if ([[[_caseDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"key"] isEqualToString:@"Procedure"]) {
        [cell setLabelsWithKey:[[_caseDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"key"] AndValue:[self.model valueForKey:@"var_procedureName"]];
    }else {
        [cell setLabelsWithKey:[[_caseDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"key"] AndValue:[[_caseDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"value"]];
    }

    OKProcedureTemplateVariablesModel *variableModel = _procedureVariables[indexPath.row];
    cell.variable = variableModel.value;
    [cell showLabelAndHideButtons];
    cell.delegate = self;
    [cell setUpCellType];
} else if (indexPath.row == _procedureVariables.count) {
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n\n %@", [_templateDictionary objectForKey:@"indicationText"], [_templateDictionary objectForKey:@"procedureText"] ];
    [cell showDescription:text];
    NSLog(@"cell.caseDataDescriptionTextView.font.fontName = %@", cell.caseDataDescriptionTextView.font.fontName);
}

cell.procedureID = _procedureID;
[tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];

return cell;
```

}

I'm just trying to figure out how to keep the selected state of these cells once the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is called. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: did you try `self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;`

Comment: Yes I am doing that on my viewDidLoad method

    self.caseDataTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
    self.caseDataTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;

I also have it enabled on my view for my storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i tried to simulate your situation, created a customCell and saved the indexpaths of selectedRows in my custom `selectedPaths` mutable array(initialized in `viewDidLoad`).
After every click i removed or added related indexpath to my array. 
it worked for my case. Hope it helps.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"caseData";
    NOTableViewCell *cell = (NOTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"new cell created for row %d", (int)indexPath.row);
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NOTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if ([selectedPaths indexOfObject:indexPath] != NSNotFound) // this cell is in selected state. 
    {
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"This cell selected"];//selected state job.
        return cell;
    }
        [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if ([selectedPaths indexOfObject:indexPath] != NSNotFound) {
        [selectedPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    }
    else{
        [selectedPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }
    //[tableView reloadData];

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];//instead of reloading all just reload clicked cell.
}
```

Comment: Where did you get selectedPaths from?

Comment: i created it.it is initially blank. and when user selects the row i add the related indexpath or remove if it is already added.

Comment: I get use of undeclared identifier selectedPaths.

Comment: yes, define it in interface as `NSMutableArray *selectedPaths;` and initialize it in `viewDidLoad` as `selectedPaths = [NSMutableArray new];`

Comment: Thanks for doing this code. It took me some time to figure out how it worked together. I used your code and then the hideLabelAndShowButtons method (mentioned above) to select the cells when the cellForRowAtIndexPath method would be called. Thanks again very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the cell to selected and not selected explicitly **in both directions** in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

If not, the recycled cells will just show the value of the cell the cell was last used for until you change it.

Comment: How would I do that? cell.selected = YES?

Also when you say both directions, could you clarify?

Comment: I think you are using something like `[cell hideLabelAndShowButtons]`. You would also need the reverse of that. But you could of course use the `UITableViewCell`'s `setSelected:animated` method (and override it if needed in your subclass).

Comment: In both directions means that you should set up selected and non-selected states explicitly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` something like this: `if (_yourObject.needToBeSelected) {cell.selected = YES;} else {cell.selected = NO;}`

Answer (score 0):

While you are invoking the delegate method in order to call `hideLabelAndShowButtons`, you aren't telling the table view that you have selected the row;

```
- (IBAction)editButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    for (int i = 0; i < self.caseDataTableView.numberOfSections; i++) {
        for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.caseDataTableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; r++) {
            NSIndexPath *path=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:i];
            [caseDataTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
            [self tableView:caseDataTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
        }
    }
 }
```

Also, you aren't using the cell selection state in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so you probably need to change some code there too, but I am not sure what the relationship is between selected state and how you want to render the cell.